# Elastic Beanstalk and Cron tasks not sure if its working with Yii

Tags: amazon-web-services, yii, ssh, cron, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am having a problem with getting a simple cron task set up on Elastic Beanstalk. I have found some of the other questions on here useful, but i still can't seem to get the cron to execute. I am unsure if it is an AWS issue, or if the script itself is not executing. The script is set up inside YII as a Console Command. I am not finding any PHP errors, and the ec2 instance is loaded without errors. Here is what i have done so far:

I have created a folder on the root of my application called .ebextensions.

Within that folder i have created a configuration file with the contents

```
# Installing dos2unix in case files are edited on windows PC
 packages:
     yum:
        dos2unix: []
 container_commands:
     01-command:
        command:         dos2unix -k cron_setup.sh

     02-command:
        command:         chmod 700 cron_setup.sh

     03-command:
         command:        "cat .ebextensions/cron_task.txt > /etc/cron.d/cron_task && chmod 644 /etc/cron.d/cron_task"
         # leader_only prevents problems when EB auto-scales
         leader_only:    true
```

the file cron_task.txt exists inside the .ebextensions folder with the contents

```
    # The newline at the end of this file is extremely important.  Cron won't run without it.
* * * * *  /bin/php /var/www/html/crons.php test  > /dev/null
```

Crons.php is a file at the root of the application that includes the Yii framework

```
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG',true);

// including Yii
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).$yii.'/yii.php');

// we'll use a separate config file
$configFile=dirname(__FILE__).'/protected/config/cron.php';

// creating and running console application
Yii::createConsoleApplication($configFile)->run();
```

the config/cron.php file is a setup file for the framework, includes database connection and model inclusions, etc

and the cron script being referenced in the cron_task.txt file is a console command that looks like this

```
class TestCommand extends CConsoleCommand {
    public function run($args) {
        $message = new Crontasks();
        $message->timestamp = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $message->message = "test";
        $message->insert();
    }
}
```

here i am just trying to get a record into the database to prove the cron was executed successfully. And i can't seem to get a record added.

The problem is, i don't know where this is failing. I am not getting any instance errors. And i took a snapshot log and cant seem to find any relevant errors in there either. Should php errors be logged here? OR do i have to set it up myself to log errors? The problem, i am also having trouble getting into ec2 via SSH. I am getting a permission denied (public key) error!! Even though i have set up the security group/key pair and using the correct public DNS for the instance!

If anyone can see anything obvious is what im doing wrong here, please let me know! Otherwise could you give any advice on where to look for any errors that might be preventing this cron task to execute? Many thanks!!

Comment: try creating a wrapper shell which changes to the required directory and then calls crons.php.

Comment: I originally had the command as `bash cron_setup.sh` and inside the sh i had `echo "* * * * * cd /bin/php /var/www/html/crons.php test" > /tmp/mycron` but that didnt work either. Is that what you were referring to?

Comment: cd /var/www/html/ ; crons.php test

Comment: PLEASE try your command from the command line. If it does not work from the command line, it is not going to work from a cron script. Period.

Comment: yes, obviously testing from the command line was the very first thing i attempted, but as mentioned above in my original post, i am unable to SSH into the server, i am getting "permission denied (public key) to which i can't seem to solve either despite a great deal of effort, but that's a whole other issue.